# how to handle ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED error

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, puppeteer

So I read about some bug and https ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED. My concern is how do I handle this in puppeteer?

My current issue is if this error occurs, puppeteer literally waits like 10 minutes until it's finally thrown. The browser just shows waiting for .... and it waits and waits.

I tried navigationtimeout, but that doesn't seem to do the trick. Anyway to force puppeteer to stop much earlier instead of just waiting for the page what seems like indefinitely?

Answer (score 1):

```
await page.goto("https://www.example.com" , {
    waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'
}).catch(err => {
    if(err.message.includes("ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED") || err.message.includes("ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED")){
        return "ERR_PROXY_FAILED";
    }else if(err.message.includes("Navigation Timeout")){
        return "ERR_SLOW_CONNECTION";
    }else if(err.message.includes("Protocol error")){
        return "ERR_UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL";
    }else{
        throw err;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since puppeteer uses async functions a lot, a good approach to handle its errors it to use try...catch. Example:

```js
// when inside an async function:

// supose I have access to `browser` and `page` objects here, outside try...catch
try {
  // do something with browser/page that may result in errors. Example:
  const response = await page.goto('https://www.google.com', { waitUntil: 'load', timeout: 10000 });
  // do something with the results...
catch (error) {
  // if something in the "try" fails, you have access to `page` and `browser` objects here
  // and you can treat the errors, or simply log to console and close the page/browser. E.g.:
  if (error.message.includes('ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED')) {
    console.log('Oopps...');
    await page.close();
    await browser.close();
  } else {
    // try again, maybe...
  }
}
```

You can do something similar if you prefer to use the traditional .then() and .catch() promise methods:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
puppeteer.launch()
  .then(browser => browser.newPage()
    .then(page => page.goto('https://aldfkjasldfj')
      .then(response => {
        // do something with the response if all is good
      })
      .catch(reason => {
        console.log(reason.message);
        console.log('closing the page and the browser');
        page.close().then(() => browser.close());
      })
    )
  );
```

Very sorry about the above code. You can see that .then() and .catch() is very ugly. :)  I prefer the async/await one.

Comment: the problem is it takes 10 minutes to throw connection closed, it just tries to load the page for 10 minutes..... it should just stop after 30 seconds as that's the default timeout. It seems it's ignoring the timeout

Comment: Hi Elsid. That seams very weird. Can you share de code? You are using page.setDefaultTimeout ?

Comment: Elsid.. I'm remembering that I had something similar a time ago. The problem was a combination of opening devtools (chrome "headed") and using page.setRequestInterception(true) to allow/cancel some requests. In this scenario I'm sure the blink is buggy and was behaving weird with just 2 POST requisitions if just one site. That was driving me crazy for days, and in the end I found that the behavior only occurred with this combination: devtools + .setRequestInterception(true). To solve the issue I've added a little delay (300ms) after devtools is open and before starting navigation.

Comment: [...continuing] I'm pretty sure it's a bug with Blink and move on with this work around. Any way.... maybe you are facing something similar. It may be ??